# Angular component with NgZorro Input inside and Storybook

Tags: angular, less, storybook, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to implement custom component uses NgZorro components and test it through Storybook. First (as described in numerous articles) I created a component story:

```js
export default {
  component: SomeComponent,
  title: 'Some Component',
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [NzInputModule, SomeComponentModule]
    }
  ]
} as Meta;

export const Test: Story<SomeComponentModule> = () => ({
  template: `<app-some-component>
    <input nz-input nzSize="small"/>
  </app-some-component>`
});
```

At that stage I have got working storybook with input but without NgZorro styles applied. Next, I updated .storybook/preview.js with:

```js
import '../src/style.less';
```

And .storybook/main.js with:

```js
  ...
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rule.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'less-loader',
        options: {
          lessOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true
          }
        }
      }]
    };
    return config;
  }
}
```

When I ran 'npm run storybook' it printed out an error about:

```sh
ERROR in ./src/style.less
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


// ================================================================
.table-size(~'middle', @table-padding-vertical-md, @table-padding-horizontal-md, @table-font-size-md);
^
Operation on an invalid type
      Error in node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\table\style\size.less (line 53, column 0)
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js 1:0-48
 @ ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
```

And I'm stucking on that place. Is there a something wrong with Ng-Zorro itself? Or what?